PrestaShop - update stock quantity problem
I have a problem with update quantity in ps_stock_availabe table
I am trying to run query:

$query = "UPDATE `"._DB_PREFIX_."stock_available` SET quantity='".$quantity."' WHERE (id_product_attribute = '".$ID_product_attribute."' AND id_product = '".$ID_product."' )";

Db::getInstance()->Execute($query);

and nothing happen. Values are correct and not null.
I can update 'manually' via PHPMyAdmin - but can not with script.
No errors in server log.
I am running update in my module in Hook:
public function hookActionProductAttributeUpdate($params) {}
other stuff in this Hook is updating without any problem.
What am I missing??

Anyone who wants to shout at the OP for concatenating PHP variables and creating an SQL injection risk should review the PrestaShop documentation and see that this framework's DB class does not provide methods for prepared statements. There are numerous CVE's reported for SQL injection vulnerabilities in PrestaShop. Google for "PrestaShop SQL injection." It's basically a dumpster fire.

However - I still do not know why quantitities do not update...

I'd guess one of: (1) the SQL UPDATE did not match any rows, (2) the value you set was already the value on the rows, so there was no net change, or (3) you didn't commit the transaction (though PrestaShop appears to have no support for transactions). It could also be weird cases like a trigger undoes your change, but you haven't mentioned any trigger.

Your code does not show that you are checking the result of the call to execute the query. How do you know it executed without error?

The query itself it is OK - when I change table - update works with the same values, I am thinking that Presta is blocking the update some how...Trying to debug that

I am tryng to update in hook: hookActionProductAttributeUpdate - my quess it has something to do with it...

Your SQL query is not enough.
Instead, you should use PrestaShop's core function designed for this: StockAvailable::setQuantity($id_product, $id_product_attribute, $quantity)
Alternatively, if you wand to add or remove quantity from stock instead of setting a new one, you can also use the following function: StockAvailable::updateQuantity($id_product, $id_product_attribute, $delta_quantity) where $delta_quantity can be positive or negative depending on if you want to add or remove quantity.

the thing is that even with Presta class StockAvailable::updateQuantity($id_product, $id_product_attribute, $delta_quantity) in that hook -> hookActionProductAttributeUpdate I can not update, outside the hook update works either with my SQL statement or with Presta StockAvailable::updateQuantity

But I agree, now I see that StockAvailable::setQuantity($id_product, $id_product_attribute, $quantity) is the right way to update

But it is still not working ? Even with setQuantity ?

Sorry for late feedback- yeah StockAvaiable::setQuantity is the good way - it works. thx
